# How to choose DB while designing application architecture?

Tags: architecture

What are the deciding factors for choosing DB while defining the application architecture?
How architects decides whether he/she need Oracle or MySQL or any other DB for this case, what are those deciding parameters? Pls guide

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question to include more information? At its current state this is too broad to provide a meaningful answer. Could you potentially list the RDBMS'es that you are considering, and/or provide some characteristics you are looking for in the end product, aka. website, front-end, anck-end, storage, small, large etc.

Comment: Thanks @Cninroh, for example I'm looking to design a web application, and I've OracleDB, MySQL, SQLServer and DB2 to choose from.

Comment: Essentially all of the options you mentioned can achieve similar results and performance characteristics, however - will have completely different TCO costs, workforce requirements, engineering requirements etc. if your aim is to run a Wordpress website for 10 000 views per month, MySQL would be the best choice. If you need a 15 000 transactions per second multi-hundred TB banking system you most likely will choose Oracle. I would suggest you share more details about the nature of the application you are considering to further narrow down considerations etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of factors that should be considered when choosing a database for your application, here are just a couple of them that I can think of right now:

- What storage model is appropriate for your application? Does it map on a relational model, or rather on a key-value (no-SQL) model? This factor has wide implications in the evolvability and the performance of your system. If you decide that a relational model is better suited for your app (based on the examples you mentioned), then you may need to think about some aspects in this context:
- How is the ecosystem around that DB? Are there any frameworks/tools that I can easily integrate into my own backend tech stack? How mature they are?
- Do you need some features provided by commercial DBs, for example distributed storage (provided by OracleDB), or you are better off with the features provided by MySQL? [Here](https://www.xplenty.com/blog/oracle-vs-mysql/) is a good 1:1 comparison between them. You can search for pros and cons for any combination of databases and you'll definitely find something useful on the web.
- Are there any performance constraints set up-front for your app? In most systems, the database becomes the main bottleneck for the performance of the application. You should compare the DBs based on some key metrics that are relevant for you (number of supported connections, distributivity / scalability, etc.)

Of course, those are just a couple of key points and it makes sense to consider them according to the projected scale of your project.